# Can IAM users pay for services on my AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have domains, instances, and buckets open on my AWS account - some are running databases on them.

I can't pay monthly for all of these services, because some of them aren't my own - I did them as work for others. And rather than going through the hassle of transferring the compute and database to another instance on another account, I'd like an IAM user to pay with his/her credit card for the services he owns.

Can IAM users pay monthly for services on my AWS account? If so, how?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you should find that IAM users don't "own" the services they deploy.  The IAM user is an agent for the account, which owns all the services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There's no mechanism for what you want.

You may be interested in [Amazon DevPay](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/devpay/), which is *sort of* like what you're asking for. But I think you're doing contract work for individuals and DevPay is aimed more at providing an AWS-like service atop AWS and selling it to other developers.

The other direction is to make your clients create an AWS account. If you want to be fancy, you could use [Consolidated Billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html) to create a sub-account under your control but billed to the customer. I think this is the best fit for consulting work, but getting there from your current setup will be painful.

Comment: i vote for Consolidated Billing and that's what I want to answer as well.

Comment: Nice... I almost forgot about the DevPay, apparently because of some small restrictions (funds earned through the sale of Amazon DevPay applications can only be withdrawn to U.S. bank accounts). Though the consolidated billing looks useful too :)

Answer (score 2):

There are some services (S3, ..) where you can let the client pay per call,  bu for the rest I believe that your account is only yours. What I do is presenting the detailed billing and I let the company reimburse the costs.

Maybe you will have to migrate the environment. If your clients are not proficient aws users, you may want to build a cloud formation script that would enable them to start and access the environment in a few clicks..

G.